# How to implement Restangular in a MEAN.js application?

Tags: angularjs, rest, express, mean-stack, restangular

I would like to figure out how to implement `Restangular` in my `mean.js` application, i'm doing the routing with angular.js, and i'm using espress.js for the `RESTAPI`, what i want is to consume the API with Restangular.

These are some of my express routes:

```
module.exports = (function () {

    var express        = require( 'express' ),
        router         = express.Router(),
        create_product = require( './create-product.controller' ),
        list_product   = require( './list-product.controller' ),
        detail_product = require( './detail-product.controller' ),
        update_product = require( './update-product.controller' );

    router.route( '/purchases/products/new' )
        .post( create_product.post );

    router.route( '/purchases/products/list' )
        .get( list_product.get );

    router.route( '/purchases/products/:id/detail' )
        .get( detail_product.get );

    router.route( '/purchases/products/:id/update' )
        .put( update_product.put );

    return router;

})();
```

When using **$http** i would do:

```
$http.get('/purchases/products/list').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

$http.post('/purchases/products/1/update', {name: 'Eggs', description: 'White'}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

How could i do that using Restangular?

Comment: Anyone explainme why the downvote?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you actually read the documentation but

```
Restangular.all('purchases/products/list').getList().then(success,err);
```

Or

```
Restangular.all('purchases').all('products').all('list').getList().then(sucess,err);
```

Same for post

```
Restangular.all('purchases/products/1/update').post(data).then(success,error)
```

Comment: I did, but what i didn't understand was if i was able to do what you've posted, all the examples have only one path level like: `Restangular.all('purchases')...` so i was unsure.

Comment: Would you please explain me the difference between the two forms you've posted please?

Comment: Another question, does the `err` func returns anything?